# Invalid/Expired Token error with Twitter API

Tags: php, twitter, twitter-oauth

I am using Jason Mathai's PHP OAUTH library and i keep on getting an invalid/expired token error whenever i try to access a user's information with the following test code:

```
//sessions stuff here
 session_start(); 
//twitter stuff
include 'lib/EpiCurl.php';
include 'lib/EpiOAuth.php';
include 'lib/EpiTwitter.php';
include 'lib/secret.php';


    //ensure token is set for the session
    $twitterObj = new EpiTwitter($consumer_key, $consumer_secret); 
    if($_GET['oauth_token']){
    $_SESSION['o_token'] = $_GET['oauth_token'];
    }
    if(!isset($_SESSION['o_token']))
          { 
    $url = $twitterObj->getAuthorizationUrl();
         header("Location:$url");
            die();
                } 
    $o_token = $_SESSION['o_token'];

    $twitterObj->setToken($o_token);  
    $token = $twitterObj->getAccessToken();  
    $twitterObj->setToken($token->oauth_token, $token->oauth_token_secret);  
    setcookie('oauth_token', $token->oauth_token);  
    setcookie('oauth_token_secret', $token->oauth_token_secret);    
    $twitterObj = new EpiTwitter($consumer_key, $consumer_secret,$_COOKIE['oauth_token'], $_COOKIE['oauth_token_secret']);  
    $twitterInfo= $twitterObj->get_accountVerify_credentials();
    $twitterInfo->response;
    var_dump($twitterInfo->response); // this tells me the error 

                try{  

                   echo $twitterInfo->screen_name;  

                    }catch(EpiTwitterException $e){  
                       echo $e->getMessage();  
                      }
```

All the methods map directly to HTTP get calls with the twitter API I assume my problem has nothing to do with Jason's library (since it is fairly well used) but something to do with my logic. All help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Once you get a oauth_token from twitter, you are storing it into session and every time you make a request with that same stored session. Tokens have some expiry time set on server so   after some time, you start getting expiry token error.

[This link](http://www.1stwebdesigner.com/tutorials/twitter-app-oauth-php/) can give you some understanding for creating a simple twitter app.

Comment: this is the link he was using

Comment: ya but the code on link and posted code are using sessions in different place.